# Cannot send cross-domain AJAX from panel

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am making a Firefox addon, and from a Firefox addon panel, I am trying to make an AJAX request to a site.

This is what I have so far:

`package.json`

```
{
  //[...]
  "permissions": {
    "cross-domain-content": ["http://www.website.com", "https://www.website.com"]
  }
}
```

`main.js`

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var extension_panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("menu.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("menu.js")
});
//[...]
```

`menu.js`

```
//[...]
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://www.website.com/currentUser",
    success: function(e){
        $("#loading").hide();
    },
    error: function(e){
        $("#loading").hide();
        if (e.status == 401){
            show_login();
            return;
        }
        show_login();
        $("#login-error").text("Couldn't check login status!").show();
    }
});
//[...]
```

Every time I run this addon, it keeps giving the `Couldn't check login status!` message.
When I log the error object, the `status` is `404`, and `statusText` is `"error"`.

I think I have everything properly set up in `package.json`, so why is the addon not allowing me to make the AJAX request?

**EDIT**

`404` in this case doesn't mean that the URL doesn't exist. In the Chrome version of this very extension, everything works fine, so I know that the website hasn't changed on a last-minute basis.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, but in the Chrome version of this very addon, the URL works just fine.

Comment: might need additional headers also. Check API docs

Comment: @charliefl What headers? The website is made to return a `200` when the user is logged in, and a `401` for every other request.

Comment: It looks like you're using jquery. So the ajax is coming not off of the "background" page (google chrome ext dev lingo) but its coming from within the page itself, which of course doesnt allow cross domain xhr. you'll have to xhr from the non-contentScript scope, this should work. im not familiar with addon sdk so im not sure how `cross-domain-content` in package.json works but i added sdk tag that should get you better replies

Comment: @dandavis I already did the debugging. Nothing useful showed up.

Comment: @Noitidart The AJAX didn't come from Chrome's background page either. It was directly in the popup. As far as to doing the XHR from the non-contentScript scope, I've considered that, but I want to solve this puzzle first.

Comment: Let's wait for the sdk experts to answer that. However if you want to do non-contentScript scope here's the function to do it with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109620/how-to-read-html-content-of-a-specific-url-using-firefox-addon/25112976#25112976 just replace `var {Cu: utils, Cc: classes, Ci: instances} = Components;` with `const { Ci, Cu, Cc, Cr } = require('chrome');`

Comment: @Noitidart I already know how to do Addon SDK's XHR, but thanks anyway.

Comment: it's just strange that the website is supposed to return a 401 or 200 and you get a 404. if the call was blocked, you wouldn't get a 404, you would get a zero... that's why i think it's something simple.

Comment: @dandavis I'll look into it some more in a few minutes. Maybe it's the way Firefox does things, I don't really know.

Comment: A plain vanilla `XMLHttpRequest` produces the same result? jQuery is included with a `script` tag?

Comment: @paa I actually did some further testing, and learned that if I run the extension in the addon SDK via `cfx run`, it doesn't work, but if I package the extension into an .xpi file, it starts working again.

Answer (score 1):

From what I learned, it seems to be a bug in the Addon SDK.

Debugging the extension with `cfx run` disables XHR for some reason, so if I were to run install the packaged `.xpi` extension, XHR (and everything else) works again.

Comment: For a workaround, please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519440/how-to-modify-source-code-without-re-running-cfx-and-firefox-when-debugging-an-s/10519963#10519963)